# Can n't pop the current screen getting '!_debugLocked': is not true

Tags: flutter, navigation, listener, bloc

I'm using **bloc** state management for update state. I want to pop current screen to listen state changes from bloc listener but shows '!_debugLocked': is not true  on console. There are some similar question I try there solutions like:

**1st attempt:**

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
   Navigator.pop(context);
});
```

2nd attempt:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
   Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

**My BlocListener:**

```
BlocListener<CreateLabelCubit, CreateLabelState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state.networkState == NetworkState.success) {
      FlushbarHelper.createSuccess(message: 'Create Label Successful!')
          .show(context);
      //refresh label list
      labelListBloc.add(LabelListFetched());
      //& pop form create label page
      /*WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      });*/
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } else if (state.networkState == NetworkState.failure) {
      FlushbarHelper.createError(message: state.toString()).show(context);
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also :

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
 Navigator.pop(context);
});
```

EDIT

You have to use `context` from `Build` method not from `BlocListener`

like this :   [image]

and you can use inside `Navigator's` `pop` method
`Navigator.pop(_context);` [as per my example]

Comment: Hello Hardik, I already tried this solution but getting some error.

Comment: try to clean and run again

Comment: Clean and run again but still getting same error.

Comment: @YousufAli : Check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks @Hardik Mehta I solve it to use Future.delayed(const Duration(second: 3), () {
   Navigator.pop(context);
} . Here problem was showing a snack bar where duration is 3 seconds. That's why  I have to delay 3 seconds for navigation.